# Resetting I2C state using HAL in STM32L0 MCU

Tags: stm32, i2c, hal

I use I2C-tools to test firmware (HAL-based), I2C, STM32L0 MCU. When I send command to MCU (via i2cset utility), it sends an answer (received in i2cget). It works fine. If I call i2cget twice after single i2cset, it fails (which is expected behaviour). But if I execute i2cset after that error, then it also fails. So, the receive-transfer becomes broken (no callback is activated). How can it be fixed?

At the moment, `HAL_I2C_Slave_Receive_IT()` is called in `HAL_I2C_SlaveTxCpltCallback()`. `HAL_I2C_SlaveRxCpltCallback()` calls `HAL_I2C_Slave_Transmit_IT()`. Should I put `HAL_I2C_Slave_Receive_IT()` in two callbacks (receive/transmit related)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if you've solved this question. However, it is more accurate to define a flag that states that the HAL_I2C_SlaveTxCpltCallback, HAL_I2C_SlaveRxCpltCallback, and HAL_I2C_ErrorCallback functions have completed transfers or an error occurred.

maybe the following codes may be useful.  You can reinit after making deinit.

```
/**
  * @brief  Initialize and setup GPIO and I2C peripheral
  * @param  obj : pointer to i2c_t structure
  * @retval none
  */
void i2c_deinit(i2c_t *obj)
{
  HAL_NVIC_DisableIRQ(obj->irq);
#if !defined(STM32F0xx) && !defined(STM32L0xx)
  HAL_NVIC_DisableIRQ(obj->irqER);
#endif // !defined(STM32F0xx) && !defined(STM32L0xx)
  HAL_I2C_DeInit(&(obj->handle));
}


void LDC_I2C_ReInit(void)
    {
    HAL_I2C_Init(&hi2c1);
    }
```

and it has a fine example in these links.

[https://github.com/stm32duino/Arduino_Core_STM32/blob/c392140415b3cf29100062ecb083adfa0f59f8b1/cores/arduino/stm32/twi.h](https://github.com/stm32duino/Arduino_Core_STM32/blob/c392140415b3cf29100062ecb083adfa0f59f8b1/cores/arduino/stm32/twi.c)

https://github.com/stm32duino/Arduino_Core_STM32/blob/c392140415b3cf29100062ecb083adfa0f59f8b1/cores/arduino/stm32/twi.c